# C++ добавление элемента в конец динамического массива

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Помогите не могу разобраться почему не работает:
Необходимо в конец динамического массива добавить сумму его элементов.

Мой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* createArray(int*, int);
void fillArray(int*, int);
void printArray(int*, int);
void deleteArray(int*);
void addElemet(int*, int);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int num = 0;
    cout << "Введите количество элементов массива ";
    cin >> num;
    int sum = 0;
    int *pArray = NULL;
    pArray = createArray(pArray, num);
    fillArray(pArray, num);
    addElemet(pArray, num);
    printArray(pArray, num);
    deleteArray(pArray);
    return 0;
}
int* createArray(int *massiv, int number) //создание динамического массива
{
    return massiv = new int[number];    
}
void fillArray(int* massiv, int number) //ввод данных в массив
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите " << i + 1 << "-тый элемент массива ";
        cin >> massiv[i];
    }
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
}
void printArray(int* massiv, int number) // вывод массива на печать
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << massiv[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void deleteArray(int* massiv) //Очистка памяти
{
    delete[] massiv;
}
void addElemet(int *massiv, int number) //добавление элемента в конец массива
{
    int *temp = NULL;
    int numTemp = number + 1;
    int sum = 0;
    temp = createArray(temp, numTemp); // создаем временный массив
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = i; //massiv[i]; // копируем данные со старого массива
        sum += massiv[i];
    }
    temp[numTemp] = sum; // не добавляет элемент в конец массива, при выводе на экран скопированные элементы отображаются нормально, а последний отображает набор цифр 
    deleteArray(massiv); // удаляем старый массив

    massiv = createArray(temp, numTemp); 

    massiv = temp; //копируем временный массив в новый.
    deleteArray(temp); //удаляем временный массив
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Поправить, кстати, совсем несложно:

```
int * addElemet(int *massiv, int number) //добавление элемента в конец массива
{
    int *temp = NULL;
    int numTemp = number + 1;
    int sum = 0;
    temp = createArray(temp, numTemp); // создаем временный массив
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = massiv[i]; // копируем данные со старого массива
        sum += massiv[i];
    }
    temp[number] = sum; // добавляет элемент в конец массива, при выводе на экран скопированные элементы отображаются нормально, а последний отображает набор цифр 
    deleteArray(massiv); // удаляем старый массив
    return temp
}
```

и в `main`:

```
pArray = addElemet(pArray, num);
```

Эдакий plain C style получается.

Чтобы уж совсем олдскульно выглядело:

```
    int * addElemet(int *massiv, int number) //добавление элемента в конец массива
{
    int *temp = NULL;
    temp = createArray(temp, number+1); // создаем временный массив
    temp[number] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        temp[number] += (temp[i] = massiv[i]); // копируем данные со старого массива
    deleteArray(massiv); // удаляем старый массив
    return temp
}
```

Максимально лаконично:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int * add_element(int *source, int size) {
    int *dest = new int[size+1], i;
    for (i = 0, dest[size]=0; i<size; i++)
        dest[size] += (dest[i] = source[i]);
    delete[] source;
    return dest;
}

int main()
{
    const int size = 5;
    int *initial = new int[size], i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        initial[i] = i;
    int *result = add_element(initial, size);
    for (i=0; i<=size; i++)
        cout << result[i] << endl;
}
```

вывод на консоль:

```
0
1
2
3
4
10
```

Comment: То есть если присваиваться будет не тому же самому массиву - `pArray2 = addElemet(pArray, num);`, то _pArray_ просто удалится и мы об этом не узнаем, пока с ним что-то делать не захотим?

Comment: @Grundy - да. Издержки изначальной реализации. Я не переписывал код, я его правил, но получилось (ИМХО) довольно изящно.

Comment: эт да :-) еще бы и цикл куда нить убрать :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ну, сумму без цикла я не умею. А так можно строчек до трех сократить, но читабельность пострадает.

Comment: @andy.37, эт да без цикла проблематично, а зачем _*temp_ сначала _NULL_ присваивать и сразу же потом присваивать значение из _createArray_? ага, вижу, у автора так же

Comment: @Grundy - я изначально написал просто `int *temp;`. Но потом подумал, что он передается аргументом в `createArray`, читать ее мне стало лень, а вдруг там проверка какая на `NULL`... Так-то в целом ни `createArray` ни `deleteArray` нафиг не нужны.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в функции `void addElemet(int *massiv, int number)`.

Дело в том, что вы передаёте `int *massiv` по значению, а значит, изменения переменной `massiv` внутри функции не видны снаружи.

Если это учебное задание, придумывайте сами, как выкручиваться.

Если это production-код, наплюйте на ручное управление памятью и переходите на `std::vector`.

Comment: Еще одна проблема вот тут: `temp[numTemp] = sum;`. Должно быть `temp[numTemp-1] = sum;` или `temp[number] = sum;`

Comment: @andy.37: Точно!

Comment: ну, и вот это: `massiv = temp; deleteArray(temp)` - внушает

Comment: Ой, да. Функция _очень_ плоха.

Answer (score 3):

Прежде всего нет никакого смысла передавать в функцию `createArray` указатель.

```
int* createArray(int*, int);
                 ^^^^
```

Параметры функции являются ее локальными переменными, которые содержат копии аргументов, которые передаются по значению.

Проще было бы определить эту функцию следующим образом

```
int * createArray( int number ) //создание динамического массива
{
    return new int[number];    
}
```

По этой же причине функция `addElemet`  либо должна возвращать указатель на вновь созданный массив, либо параметр `massiv` следует объявить как ссылку. К тому же значение переменной, задающей размер массива, также должно измениться.

Кроме того непонятно, почему в этом цикле выражение `massiv[i]` закомментировано, а вместо него используется выражение `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    temp[i] = i; //massiv[i]; // копируем данные со старого массива
    sum += massiv[i];
}
```

И в этом предложении

```
temp[numTemp] = sum;
```

происходит выход за границу допустимых индексов для массива. Так как последний допустимый индекс - это `numTemp - 1`.

И в этих предложениях

```
massiv = createArray(temp, numTemp); 
//...
deleteArray(temp); //удаляем временный массив
```

нет смысла.

Я бы определил эту функцию следующим образом

```
int addElemet( int * &massiv, int number ) //добавление элемента в конец массива
{
    int *temp = createArray( number + 1 );

    int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = massiv[i];
        sum += massiv[i];
        // или можно записать в одну строчку
        // sum += temp[i] = massive[i];
    }
    temp[number] = sum;

    deleteArray( massiv ); // удаляем старый массив

    massiv = temp; //копируем временный массив в новый.

    return number + 1;
}
```

В main вызов этой функции будет выглядеть как

```
num = addElemet(pArray, num);
```

Не забудьте также изменить объявления измененных фукнуий перед main

```
int * createArray( int number );
int addElemet( int * &massiv, int number );
```

Также в main переменная `sum` не используется и может быть удалена.